# Finding duplicates within a vector in R

Tags: r

So I need to write an R program that takes a vector x and checks if x has any duplicate element. I can't use any vectorized operation or R’s built-in function. This is what I have so far, not sure how to move forward. When I run this I get hit with

*"Error in if (x[i] == x[j]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"*

[image]

Comment: can you edit your question to add your code as a MarkDown code block? (instead of an image; images are hard to copy-paste :) ) https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks

Comment: Is `table` a "vectorized operation"?